# Install spindle in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tapestry

I want to learn tapestry framework. So i began with http://www.sitepoint.com/jakarta-tapestry/
I am using eclipse indigo version 1.

I am having problem in installation of spindle plugin.
Can anyone tell me how to do this.

How I have tried:-
1. Go to install software
2. Click on add
3. Add the site name as:http://spindle.sf.net/updates and plugin name as spindle

But it shows No items available. And i can do nothing beyond this point.

Can anyone please tell me where i am wrong.

Comment: Pluggins are coming in my eclipse.May be there is some problem in your eclipse.

Comment: Which version of eclipse are you using ?
I am using eclipse indigo version 1
Ca you see spindle plugin specially..I can also see other plugins but not this one specially..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tutorial is from February 2006 and is using Tapestry 3 by the looks of it. The current version of Tapetsry is 5.3 which has changed a lot and is way more powerful. Check out the [tapestry tutorial](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry-tutorial.html) on the [tapestry website](http://tapestry.apache.org/).